# Tried learning hibernate, gives errors about wrong sql syntax

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm practicing JPA/Hibernate and when running the following code:

```
package com.newjpa;

import javax.persistence.*;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("book");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
        et.begin();
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setAuthor("1423414");
        book.setTitle("#143441");
        book.setRating(4);
        book.setYear(2093);
        book.setDescr("13471863146486348626424372");
        em.merge(book);
        et.commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();

    }
}
```

And the Book class (without getters and setters):

```
package com.newjpa;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long bookId;
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private int year;
    private int rating;
    private String descr;


    public Book(String author, String title, int year, int rating, String descr) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.descr = descr;
    }

    public Book() {
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'value for hibernate_sequence' at line 1
```

I don't really know what that means and how to solve it, I've spend last couple hours searching and can't find anything similar to that.
persistence.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
<persistence-unit name="book" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
 </provider>
    <class>com.newjpa.Book</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url  " 
 value="jdbc:mysql://www.remotemysql.com:3306/placeholder" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
 value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" 
 value="placeholder" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" 
 value="placeholder" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
 value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I can't really find any errors here - I saw very similar code in many places on the internet. As pointed out by another user, here is the sql statement that hibernate generates:
create table Books (
bookId bigint not null,
author varchar(255),
descr varchar(255),
rating integer not null,
title varchar(255),
year integer not null,
primary key (bookId)
)
It's worth pointing out that the table is created, the problem is the exception and the fact my created entity isn't inserted into the table.
Important update: I found that hibernate generates also before this one line this one:

```
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
```

and after the table creation this one:

```
Hibernate: 
    call next value for hibernate_sequence
```

Which seems to be associated with the problem

Comment: The `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` annotations are attached to whatever field immediately follows them - which in your case is `private String author;` - which is obviously not what you want - and the data types will not match, also. So, I assume you are missing an actual field for the auto-generated ID - something like `private long bookId;`

Comment: did it, still shows the same error

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show the updated attempt. It may not have solved your problem, but it is something which still needed to be fixed. Also, you can show us your Hibernate config file. Use `<property name="show_sql">true</property>`, if it is not already present, and then also show us the generated SQL statement.

Comment: ok, I'll do that in a moment

Comment: Done it, it's literally everything I've written

Comment: Warning: If those are real database account details, and a real password, you should immediately change the password (and then also replace those specific details in this question with something which is obviously just placeholder text).

Comment: Those aren't real per se, all the info here was created for this one excercise and will be destroyed afterwards - it's not anything I'm using anywhere and the database is also empty. Thanks for the care tho, just to be safe I changed the values

Comment: I also managed to squeeze out some more info from hibernate which I added in the edition. Also thank you for the help, even if it doesn't work I appreciate the time you spent.

Comment: Ah - your Hibernate dialect value is set to H2 `value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"` - but you want to use MySQL: `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`. I assume the tutorial uses H2, and you wanted to use MySQL.

Comment: YES. I can't believe I didn't see it. It still generates some error about a nonexisting table with a name consisting of my username and .hibernate_sequence. This is another topic and I'll try to solve it myself first, thank you so much for your help

Comment: You may be using MySQL 8 - in which case, use that specific dialect: `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`.

Comment: I still got some exception - but the code works, creates a table, puts the book and returns 0. Thank you so much, I didn't even realize such nuances about individual versions or some other things.

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and provide full details of your changes/fixes if you think it will help other people in the future.

Comment: Just did it; hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had two problems: I had wrong dialect set (org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect instead of org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect) AND it turns out when using MySQL 8 you have to change the dialect from "MySQLDialect" to "MySQL8Dialect.